# Is it a matter of connection between my workspace and the data base or what?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I've created a data base in `Mysql`; and a forum in a `jsp` page to verify the data received but But I've encountered a problem and I do not know the reason

> error :message An exception occurred processing JSP page /massar.jsp at line 24

Code :

```
String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/massar";
String user = "root";
String password = "!!!!";

String sql = "select massar_profil from massar.massar_user";

try {
  Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
   con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
   ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
   rs = ps.executeQuery(); 
 %>
```

'

Comment: Please edit the post to make it readable. The error quoted is about: "massar.jsp at line 24". How can anybody help without seeing it ?

Comment: line number 24 is  : Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();

Comment: i don't know how to put all the code bcs it's too long

Comment: Very good. Posting all code is not advisable. Post [mcve]

Comment: 'Connection con= null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/massar";
String user = "root";
String password = "!!!";

String sql = "select massar_profil from massar.massar_user";

    try {
    Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();'

Comment: how can i send you all the code so that you can see clearly what's the matter

Comment: You can't.  As c0der says, you need to **write** an MCVE, and put it into the Question.

Answer (score 0):

If the error occured on this line:

```
  Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
```

then the most likely explanation is that the `Class.forName(driverName)` has failed to load the JDBC driver.  And the most likely explanation for that is that the JAR file containing the JDBC driver has not been included in the runtime classpath for your webapp.  Check that the JAR is in your WAR file's "/WEB-INF/lib" directory.

If this doesn't solve your problem, please get your JSP to produce a stacktrace, and show it to us.

Comment: i ve chekc the jar file and it exist already i've changed with another one but still have the same  prob

Comment: Stacktrace:
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: We need to see the stacktrace for the exception that was thrown at massar.jsp at line 24

Comment: i did't get you !!

Comment: you mean this : org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /massar.jsp at line 25

Comment: No.  I mean the stacktrace for that exception.  The stacktrace for *"[the] exception [that] occurred processing JSP page /massar.jsp at line 25"*.  And if you can't find the stacktrace anywhere ... modify your JSP to catch that exception and output the stracktrace.  (BTW.  Your question says line 24 not line 25.)

Comment: this is tha stacktrace that it gives me :Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mysql-connector-java-5.1.39

Comment: That is not a stacktrace.  You have made a mistake copying it.  And put it into the question, not into comments.

Comment: Unless you understand my comments, I don't think I can help you.  Sorry.

Comment: thnaks for your time :)